# Mildew at the base of exterior block wall

Tags: drainage, mold, landscaping, flashing, concrete-block

The back wall of my row house is made of uninsulated block with a cement coating that looks like stucco. There is mildew / mold on the wall at the ground level that has slowly been getting worse.

The top of the wall is a low parapet thats is capped with limestone slabs and has a railing. I don't see any flashing under the limestone.
The back yard is made up of 2" thick slate flagstones that run right up to the back of the wall.
I pulled up the slate, dug down through a few inches of sand and at the footer there is a tile drain that I assume goes to an indoor pit.

Whats the best way to clean off this mildew and how can I prevent it from coming back?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A 50/50 mixture of water and chlorine bleach is the usual prescription for cleaning mildew.

To clean, spray it on. Leave it soak in for about 15 minutes. Scrub with a broom and rinse well.

To keep it from coming back?   You can't.  Not without unrealistic actions, like making the area stay dry constantly and have sun all day so the organism cannot grow.

You have to resign yourself to cleaning and in the future clean it again.

You could repaint the walls with a thick paint with mildew resistant qualities. However in time that will deplete with the wear of the elements and fail.
Also seal the cement squares well so there are no pockets for water and the spores to collect and grow. ( This will make them slippery. not a good situation)

So alas, you are destined, like the rest of us to fight mildew on a regular basis.

Comment: What's growing on the pavers looks like lichen to me. Solution is still the same as in the answer. Or power wash every year